# Удаление элемента из массива по ключу со сдвигом ключей

Tags: php, массивы

перерыл уже гугл но так и не нашел адекватного решения корректно работающего

есть много мерный массив

```
$lls[2]['keys']
```

структура такова если отобразить var_dump($lls[2]['keys']);

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "red"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

нужно удалить значение по ключу 0 например вот так unset($lls[2]['keys'][0])

но что бы после этого ключи сместились массив не выглядел так

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

а принял такой вид

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

по тому что например вот такой способ который советовали не работает

```
unset($lls[2]['keys'][0]);
$cleark = $lls[2]['keys'];
$lls[2]['keys'] = array_diff($cleark, array(''));
```

мне кажется в php должна быть какая то простая функция для этого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `array_values`

```
$arr = [1 => 'test', 2 => 'test2'];
print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [1] => test
    [2] => test2
)



$arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test2
)
```

Comment: ток хотел сказать(

Comment: @Jean-Claude сорян :)